# Access the Google api using Extjs 4.2

Tags: javascript, google-maps, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have tried to access the following url using Extjs sencha. Data not loaded on run time. When i try to access the url on browser i am able to see the data
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true&key=API_KEY.

I am newbie for Extjs.I know i am trying to load the cross domain data.But i dont know how to achieve this. Please somebody help me

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyJsonStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: [
    'MyApp.model.MyModel',
    'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
    'Ext.data.reader.Json'
],

constructor: function(cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
        model: 'MyApp.model.MyModel',
        storeId: 'MyJsonStore',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Barcroft + Plaza +Apartments ,+22041&sensor=true&key=API_KEY',
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        },
        listeners: {
            load: {
                fn: me.onJsonstoreLoad,
                scope: me
            }
        }
    }, cfg)]);
},

onJsonstoreLoad: function(store, records, successful, eOpts) {
    Ext.MessageBox.show('Loaded');
}
```

});

Instead of Ajax proxy i have tried jsonp also.If i use jsonp then i am getting uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token .I have searched so many blogs, forums everybody talked about adding callback but i am calling third party api

I have tried following code for jsonp.I Have tried both ways like with and without callback key

```
proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true&key=API_KEY',
            callbackKey: 'Mycallback',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'results'
            }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "access url", "data not loaded". Maybe you can show the relevant code?

Comment: I think you're problem is cors. In the console you should get some sort of warning about it.  You basically can't make cross site requests across domain unless the web service is cors enabled.  JsonP is a work around for this, however, i don't believe that service will except a callback.

Comment: Hi hgoebl i have updated the code over there .Please check.

Comment: Hi Weeksdev. Is there anyway to call this service as a callback.If so can you give me a piece of code for that.That will be great help

Comment: Do you have some sort of back-end that can make calls for you?  I'm thinking something along the lines of a [middle tier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture): you hit your endpoint (the middle tier), which then makes a call on the behalf of the user and returns the data, thus, CORS should not be an issue, and you wouldn't have to do JSONP, either.

Comment: Another option is to use the [Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple).  This is the route i would go if you do not want to make the call server-side (since jsonp is not supported)

Comment: I have used php to load the api and called using ajax proxy from same server.Thanks all for your help